# Display variable in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET page I have a search box that is currently working as expected. What I would like to do is leave the searched value in that textbox after searching (the search opens a new page, though I'm retaining the search value from querystring). I can confirm the variable is being retained correctly by using the value `<%= search%>` in my aspx, however when I try to show that in my textbox nothing displays. I have searched dozens of forum posts and the nearest I can tell is that I need to databind this textbox. I'm not sure where my mistake is, but this is the closest I have come up with:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# search %>'></asp:TextBox>
Search: <%=search %>
```

With the code behind

```
public string search;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    search = Request.QueryString["search"];
    SearchTextBox.Text = search;
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if it is the first time you see the page with this

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {

}
```

And check first if the query string exist.

Comment: Doh! Something so simple. Think that means I need to call it quits for the day. ;)

Comment: Hi doby84 try to go with MVC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null && !IsPostBack)
{
     string search = Request.QueryString["search"];
     SearchTextBox.Text = search;
}
```